# could not connect to server:

Tags: postgresql, connection, localhost

New To postgres, don't know what to do, where to check. Help! Thanks

This happens when create a new server
[image]

This happens when connect to exist server.

[image]

I think they are from same problem.

Comment: Probably you didn't enable the parameter listen_addresses = '*'

Comment: Are you sure that your postgresql server is runing?

Comment: The error message contains a couple of questions you haven't answered yet. Please do this first and tell us. Then we might be able to help.

Comment: @ Dvorog,  After several inspection, I solved the problem by re-install the postgresql using 3rd party installer. Even though don't know why the original instance just can't interact with the pgadmin suddenly~~~  thanks

Comment: @Dvorog  I have checked it, it is "*". Thanks

Comment: @HolgerJakobs, next time I will be more specific. I was kinda new to it so I just threw the whole problem here.  I solved it by re-install the postgres using 3rd-party installer.